# Automatically create HTML pages on adding an item in SP 2013 list

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-foundation, splistitem, splist, item-added

So I am very new to coding. Please bear with me. We have a SharePoint list wherein we store employee details. The task is to **automatically** create a new page with predefined UI -every time a new employee is added to the list. So every employee on the list has their own page with their data. How do I go about this?
Also, only that particular employee should be able to edit that page, but all other employees should be able to view each other's pages.

Answer (score 1):

Don't think in creating pages;
Think in one (webpart)page that has dynamic content (metadata in your employee list)

Instead of solving it with code *if you have a hammer everything starts to look like a nail*
First learn what SharePoint is and does..
otherwise your approach is going to be like cooking curry in a pizza parlor

Comment: I am trying to learn but his is kind of an urgent requirement...thats why i have posted it here

Comment: It is like learning how to drive a race-car, it is easy to put the paddle to the metal... but you will die in the first corner. Same with SharePoint; now you won't die ... but you will lose data, or use the wrong data in business processes if you don't master it

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint often does need a pretty gigantic hammer to do what you want.

It is of course advisable to only create one page with filtered content for the respective user. But that obviously will restrict you in a lot of ways and isn't what you asked for.

Sadly there is no OOTB way to do it. I would recommend these workflow actions, if you are in an environment, where you can use them (easy Installation[Site Settings->Solutions->Upload):

[Custom Workflow Actions](http://ilovesharepoint.codeplex.com/releases/view/89201)